# $(Build.SourceVersion) not giving latest change set number sometimes

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In the build pipeline task(Power Shell), I try to retrieve the value of $(Build.SourceVersion) assuming it will give the latest change set number that triggered the build. But sometimes it is giving the previous change set number.

Can we force to update this variable to have the latest change set number? or Do we have any other alternative to get the latest changeset number that triggered the build?

I haven’t made any changes to the variable. In the pipeline I have added a power shell script task which accesses the environment variable called “$env:ChangeSetNumber” this environment variable is declared in Environment Variables section in the task as shown in the below image which points to “$(Build.SourceVersion)”

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62IHe.png)

The value of $(Build.SourceVersion) sometimes returns the previous change set number rather than the change set number that triggered the build.

Requirement is to get changeset number that triggered the build.

Comment: Is the pipeline task running for pull request? Or anything specific?

Comment: @VivekJaiswal Pipeline is triggered due to gated check-in.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following alternative:

```
$(system.pullRequest.sourceCommitId)
```

Comment: I believe $(system.pullRequest.sourceCommitId) is for GIT, in my case we are using TFVC. I will try.

Comment: This variable should be for TFS. It might not be documented in microsoft docs but worth a try if it works for you.

Comment: I am getting error "The term 'System.PullRequest.SourceCommitId' is not recognized as the name of a 
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program." I am using it in inline powershell task.